# How to solve "A RenderFlex overflowed by 143 pixels on the right." error in text?

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

This is my cardview code:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
        TitleText(text: "Item name mmmmmmmmm $index"),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        Body1Text(text: "Discount mmmmmmmm",color: Colors.red,),
        SizedBox(height: 5.0),
        SubHeadText(text: "Price ,mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",color: Colors.red,)

    ],
),
```

Comment: Are these widgets from a plugin?

Comment: Wrap it in Expanded()

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just Wrap you - `Card` with -`Flexible` Widget.

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Item name mmmasdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaammmmmm"),
              SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
              Text(
                "Discount mmmmmmmm",
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
              Text(
                "Price ,mmmmmmmmmdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfmmmmmmmmm",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Just Wrap your `Card`, `Text` widget with `Flexible` Widget.
And also remember that a `Flexible` widget must be a descendant of a `Row`, 
`Column`, or `Flex`. i.e `Flexible` parent widget should be one of them.

Comment: I am getting the same issue with "DropdownButtonFormField()" and structure is as  Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField().),],) Kindly suggest how can we fix renderflex overlowed by 144 pixels on the right issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Wrap` instead of `Column`.

For ex..

```
new Wrap(
   spacing: 5.0, 
   runSpacing: 5.0, 
   direction: Axis.vertical, // main axis (rows or columns)
   children: <Widget>[
       TitleText(text: "Item name mmmmmmmmm $index"),
       Body1Text(text: "Discount mmmmmmmm",color: Colors.red,),
       SubHeadText(text: "Price ,mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",color: Colors.red,)
   ],
 )
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply use

```
isExpanded: true,
```

on `DropdownButton`.

Example

```
        DropdownButton(
          isExpanded: true,
          items: data.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(item['name']),
              value: item['id'].toString(),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newVal) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newVal;
            });
          },
          value: _mySelection,
        ),
```

Comment: You are awesome!! It worked like charm. Thanks @Esinniobiwa.

Answer (score 2):

isExpanded: true, inside DropdownButtonFormField

Answer (score 1):

You can use SizedBox instead of columns.

```
SizedBox(
   child:new Wrap( 
   spacing: 5.0,
   runSpacing: 5.0, 
   direction: Axis.vertical, // main axis (rows or columns)
   children: <Widget>[
       TitleText(text: "Item name mmmmmmmmm $index"),
       Body1Text(text: "Discount mmmmmmmm",color: Colors.red,),
       SubHeadText(text: "Price ,mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",color: Colors.red,)
   ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
              Flex(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                             Expanded(
                               child:Text('')
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your using static padding and sizing. This can be a problem when it comes to rendering your project on other devices aside from this one. I'd strongly recommend using one of the following:

1. `SingleChildScrollView` under a `LayoutBuilder`.

   - Instead of a column, try using a container including a custom height and width
2. In case you decided to set custom padding, alternatively, you can use `MediaQueryData`.

I'd recommend using the first one for starters, I would be easier. The second method is for calculating the width and height of the screen and adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are other useful answers too. I am sharing my experience on this issue for those who are new and are trying to find multiple ways to fix this issue.

In my case Text() was inside Column() and I fix this issue by setting textDirection property as below:

```
textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
```

You can set the value depending on your needs.